# Yii2 how to launch console?

Tags: php, yii2

I am new to Yii2 and web development.
Could you please explain me how to launch Yii2 console, because it's not clear from the documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html. 
I understood that there is a yii console file where I can configure some commands, but how to I actually launch it?

Comment: Open `cmd` on Windows or `Terminal` on Linux, navigate to your project directory (like `/var/www/project/)`, type: `php yii`.

Comment: The thing is that project is not on localhost.

Comment: So you need `ssh` access to your server or just flush cache by `ftp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's so easy to use , 
if you don't access SSH you wont lunch console .

go to your yii directory where you can find a file named YII ( without any extaion  )

RUN that with php command

```
php yii yourconntroller-name/your-action-name
```

before that you have to create a contorller and action in it

it's a simple sample :

```
<?php

namespace console\controllers;
use yii\console\Controller;
use common\models\Post;

/**
 * Test controller
 */
class TestController extends Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {

        echo date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $p = Post::find()->where('status=0 AND  auto_publish_date IS NOT NULL  AND auto_publish_date < NOW( )  ')->all();
        foreach($p as $post){
            echo $post->id."\n";
            $post->status=1;
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
            $post->time = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $post->save();
        }

        echo "....\n".count($p)." posts has been published ...\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run in your terminal `your_project_path/yii controller/action [options]` (make sure `yii` has execute permissions).

Substitute `controller/action` by some already shipped commands (i.e.: `migrate/up`), or write your own inside the console application.

Comment: The thing is that project is not on localhost.
I want to call flush() to clear the cache on the website.

Comment: You have to access the server for you to run console command. Why dont you create custom function that you can call on the web to flush your caches